# Programming with LaTeX3

Tags: latex3

What is the best way to learn to programming in LaTeX3, and where can I get the best information in your opinion. I know that does not sound like a specific question, but I want to deepen on LaTeX and do not know where to start.I've done my research on the web and I have found dozens sites referred to LaTeX3, but which of these are appropriate for someone who starts now?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Currently, we don't have a *Programming in LaTeX3* book, and even if we did there would be lots of gaps. So there is no 'complete' solution. However, there are some resources. First, I'd point to the [introduction to LaTeX3 ideas](http://texdoc.net/pkg/expl3) which gives a broad-brush overview of the concepts. I have written a [short series of blog posts](http://www.texdev.net/index.php?s=programming+latex3) on the topic: I've [summarised the 'story so far'](http://www.texdev.net/2014/02/02/programming-latex3-a-summary-so-far/). There is also the [complete command reference](http://texdoc.net/pkg/interface3), as well as course of the questions here tagged [latex3](/questions/tagged/latex3) or [expl3](/questions/tagged/expl3).

Comment: Of course, if anyone wants to help write _Programming in LaTeX3_ they should get in touch :-)

Comment: @JosephWright very helpful :-)

Comment: @JosephWright On your blog, which do you recommend me starting with?

Comment: @azetina http://www.texdev.net/2011/12/07/programming-latex3-background/

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for the quick link but is there a specific sequence I can follow. It would be nice if there was a post in your blog that includes all posts on LaTeX3 from the beginning to current.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks a lot for the extra effort. One of my resolutions this year is to contribute more to the LaTeX community and dedicate 1 hour to learning LaTeX3 programming and your blog is definitely a good start.

Comment: @azetina http://www.texdev.net/2014/02/02/programming-latex3-a-summary-so-far/

Comment: A draft of the first chapter, “Basics”, is ready. I started the second chapter, “Conditionals”. But don't expect my “Programming in LaTeX3” to be ready before *several* months.

Comment: @egreg May I ask what the current status of "Programming in LaTeX3" is? I would like to get started with LaTeX3, and currently I am looking for adequate ressources. Is there anything that should be added to this rather outdated question?

Comment: @Matthias Situation remains unchanged

Comment: @JosephWright Can I pick up where egreg left off for the book?

Comment: @egreg I am also curious to hear the current status of "Programming in LaTeX3." If I ever master it, I would be happy to contribute.