# Learning LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3

In my attempt to venture in the realm of LaTeX3 coding, I was wondering if a list of answers, in LaTeX3, can be made? That is, a list of links to answer in which users here at TeX.SX have used such coding. This will enable me to look at this post and look at samples instead of searching for examples everywhere on the website.

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94367/how-to-define-a-command-that-bolds-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-the-input-ar) is one! Couple of answers have used LaTeX3.

Comment: Try [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+code%3A%22%5CExplSyntaxOn%22)

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84605?

Comment: @cryptic0 The question is really about `expl3`, the programming layer, which is available and usable

Comment: The LaTeX3 project was announced at conference in Prague in 1992. I was there. This is more than two decades. But users are using a provisional release (called LaTeX2e) still. And here are many of history problems (like cm-fix.sty, for example) -- they are as prisoner ball in LaTeX2e. Despite this users don't need any changes.

Comment: Not really the same question but see also [latex3 - Where I can find introduction to programming in expl3? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558814/where-i-can-find-introduction-to-programming-in-expl3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost all LaTeX3 answers will use `expl3` or `xparse` packages, or as egreg says use `\ExplSyntaxOn` (which is the LaTeX3 analogue of `\makeatletter` to allow package code in the preamble) thus a link such as

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=expl3

will show most of the things that you wish to find.

or of course those explicitly tagged:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex3

Comment: Sorry to dredge this up, but does this mean that `\ExplSyntaxOn` is similarly implicit in package/class files?

Comment: @SeanAllred It means it probably would be implicit if there were a latex3 package loading mechanism, but there isn't so far:-)

Answer (score 16):

Though the question was asked long back, for anyone who views this and would like to learn LaTeX3 Programming, [Programming LaTeX3: Creating functions](http://www.texdev.net/2011/12/14/programming-latex3-creating-functions/) provides a really good introduction with number of examples and the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) can be used for further understanding and exploration.