# Are mouse over definitions of acronyms possible?

Tags: pdf, acronyms, acro

I have a lot of acronyms in my thesis and I am using the `acro` package. I would like to know if there is an option to make it possible for the acronyms within the thesis to display a mouse over definition, this is obviously only a function useful for the PDF output file, is there a possibility to make them display the long name if the mouse is hovered over the acronym term?

**(FIXED)** Edit: problem using the `\tooltip` macro **(FIXED)**

To AlexG I encountered a problem with using the `\tooltip` macro whereby you get the following overlapping of acronyms:

[image]

I can't work out why or how to fix it, but its an essential flaw of the `\tooltip` macro as, when I remove it it disappears: please feel free to play around with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{acro}

\usepackage{tensor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The re-defining of the acronym entering commands \ac for the normal form, \acp for the plural form of the acronym, \acl, \aclp
\let\acorig\ac
\let\acporig\acp
\def\ac#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip*[black]{\acs{#1}}{\acl{#1}}}{\acorig{#1}}}
\def\acp#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip*[black]{\acsp{#1}}{\aclp{#1}}}{\acporig{#1}}}



%%%%%%%%%% THE LONG ASS MACRO
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% usage: \tooltip[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%        \tooltip*[<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%        (starred variant is not draggable)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{media9}[2014/02/06]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength{\whatsleft}
\newlength{\tipshift}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\mix_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\mix_pdfannot:nnnn\def\tpPdfLastAnn{\g_mix_pdflastann_tl}
\let\tpPdfXform\mix_pdfxform:n\def\tpPdfLastXform{\g_mix_pdflastxform_tl}
\let\tpInsertAcroForm\mix_insert_acroform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{sO{blue}mO{yellow!20}m}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    /Subtype/Screen%
    /AA<<%
      /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
        var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{fd.display=display.visible;}{%
          if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
            var click\thetcnt=false;%
            var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
          }%
          if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
            fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
          }%
        }%
        this.dirty=false;%
      )>>%
      /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{fd.display=display.hidden;}{%
        if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
        if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}this.dirty=false;%
      }%
      )>>%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
        /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
        /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
          var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
          try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
          fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
        )>>%
      }%
    >>%
  }{{\color{#2}#3}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{\fcolorbox{black}{#4}{#5}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
  \tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \hspace{\tipshift}\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#3}}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
      /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/Ff 65536/T (tip.\thetcnt)/F 3%
      /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
      \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
    }%
    \xdef\@anim@fields{\@anim@fields\space\tpPdfLastAnn}
    \tpInsertAcroForm
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page text area.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DEFINED ACRONYMS
\DeclareAcronym{pwr}{
    short = PWR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Pressurised Water Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{ebr}{
    short = EBR-I ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = Experimental Breeder Reactor I ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.exist ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{vhtr}{
    short = VHTR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Very High Temperature Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{sfr}{
    short = SFR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = Sodium Fast Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{heu}{
    short = HEU ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = High Enriched Uranium ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.term ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{leu}{
    short = LEU ,
    short-plural =  ,
    long = Low Enriched Uranium ,
    long-plural =  ,
    class = reac.term ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{htgr}{
    short = HTGR ,
    short-plural = s ,
    long = High Temperature Gas cooled Reactor ,
    long-plural = s ,
    alt = HTR ,
    class = reactor ,
}

\begin{document}

The flexibility of fuel cycle use is one of the attractive features presented by \acp{htgr}. Initially \acp{htgr} took advantage of the efficient uranium-thorium fuel cycle which combined \ac{heu} as fissile fuel with fertile thorium that would breed fissile \nuclide[233][92]{U} during operation. With the non-proliferation treaty in force by 1970 a \ac{leu} fuel cycle was designed and adopted to avoid diversion of fissile material.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am looking into it.

Comment: `fancytooltips`, `cooltooltips` and `pdfcomment` can create pop-ups I think.

Comment: See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32314/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-hover-text-to-all-incidents-of-math-mode-where-the-h

Comment: In addition to the packages mentioned by @TorbjørnT., the [`\tooltip`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005) macro for draggable tooltips which supports all known output drivers.

Comment: Thank you all for directing me, I will give it a shot. @AlexG I am still new to LaTeX, does what you mentioned `supports all known output drivers` mean that the `\tooltip` macro can be integrated with the `acro` package?

Comment: @Fiztban: In the first place it means, you can use it with `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf`, `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `latex`+`dvipdfmx`, `xelatex`. I tried to integrate it with the `acro` package. See below.

Comment: I'll have a look into it tomorrow.

Comment: `\tooltip` code has been fixed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is an example using the previously defined `\tooltip` command. Some user macros from the `Acro` package needed to be redefined to insert the tooltips only *after* first use:

[image]

For Acronyms in black and non-draggable tip boxes use

```
\def\ac#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip**[black]{\acs{#1}}{\acl{#1}}}{\acorig{#1}}\relax}
\def\acp#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip**[black]{\acsp{#1}}{\aclp{#1}}}{\acporig{#1}}\relax}
```

instead of

```
\def\ac#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip{\acs{#1}}{\acl{#1}}}{\acorig{#1}}\relax}
\def\acp#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip{\acsp{#1}}{\aclp{#1}}}{\acporig{#1}}\relax}
```

in the code below.

**The complete code:**

```
\documentclass[a6paper,12pt]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{acro}
% some acronyms
\DeclareAcronym{cd}{ short={CD}, long={Compact Disc}, short-plural={s}, long-plural={s} }
\DeclareAcronym{mc}{ short={MC}, long={Musicassette}, short-plural={s}, long-plural={s} }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The re-defining of the acronym entering commands \ac for the normal form,
% \acp for the plural form of the acronym, \acl, \aclp
\let\acorig\ac
\let\acporig\acp
\def\ac#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip{\acs{#1}}{\acl{#1}}}{\acorig{#1}}\relax}
\def\acp#1{\acifused{#1}{\tooltip{\acsp{#1}}{\aclp{#1}}}{\acporig{#1}}\relax}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2018/01/15
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]]
%            [<link colour>]{<link text>}
%            [<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%            [<x-offset>,<y-offset>]
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes,linegoal}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\let\cListSet\clist_set:Nn\let\cListItem\clist_item:Nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}mO{0pt,0pt}%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \cListSet\tpOffsets{#9}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \tipshift=0pt%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
    %OCG-based (that is, all non-draggable) boxes should not extend beyond the
    %current column as they may get overlaid by text in the neighbouring column
    \setlength\whatsleft{\linegoal}%
  }{%
    \measureremainder{\whatsleft}%
  }%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\dimexpr\twd+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax%
    \setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd-\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp+\cListItem\tpOffsets{2}}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\dimexpr\tipshift+\cListItem\tpOffsets{1}\relax}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\acp{mc} and \acp{cd} are media for recording music. The \ac{mc} appeared about 15 years earlier than the \ac{cd}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you so much its pretty much exactly what I was hoping for!! so by using the `\tooltip*` I am able to make them non draggable. Just one more question, how can I make them appear black? I would like the acronyms not stand out from the text please.

Comment: Ah worked it out just need to add the `\tooltip*[black]{...}{...}` I get a permanent error is that normal?

Comment: The error is: The \acp{mc} appeared about 15 years e...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: @Fiztban: No error here. Perhaps old version of `media9` at your end? Get `media9.sty` from [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/media9.sty) and place it into your current directory, or better run the package updater if you are using TeXLive-2013 or MikTeX-2.9.

Comment: it must be a defect of the sharelatex.com site, when I exported and implemented the example into my LaTeX editor it returned no errors. Again thank you for you amazing help, made my day! Just a side question if I may, how did you make the animated image?

Comment: @Fiztban: Some months ago I posted the method for Linux and X11 on [Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2868).

Comment: thanks for the post reference, I have added to my initial question a problem I ran into with your solution which I have been trying to fix and understand for the rest of my afternoon without much success. Have a look at it see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: @Fiztban: The bug you reported has been fixed.

Comment: Ideally you should exchange you redefinition of `acro`'s macros with the redefinition in my answer. That way all of `acro`'s macros do what they're supposed to do, e.g., starred versions will still work. My code is generic, i.e., it should work with any tooltip. The interface is `\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_tooltip:nn #1#2 { \pdftooltip {#1} {#2} }` where your `\tooltip` macro could easily be inserted.

Comment: I did end up using the macro you wrote @cgnieder and used `\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_tooltip:nn #1#2 { \tooltip*[black] {#1} {#2} }` to get the non-clickable mouseover tooltips fo `\ac` `\acp` and `\aca`. However as reported in my last comment strangely when I use the `\tooltip` macro pdf's ask to be saved upon exiting if you have mouse overed any item whereas your solution doesn't do so.

Comment: @moose What do you mean, the code or the animated gif? As for the code, an hour or two, for the gif, see my [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161464/are-mouse-over-definitions-of-acronyms-possible/161478?noredirect=1#comment369660_161478).

Comment: I mean the animated gif. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 13):

**Update 2015-09-08:**

As of version 2.1 `acro` supports tooltips directly. They can be activated in two ways:

1. simply set the option `\acsetup{tooltip=true}`. This will load the `pdfcomment` package and use `\pdftooltip` as command for creating tooltips.
2. set the option `\acsetup{tooltip-cmd = <macro>}` to a tooltip-creating macro of your liking.

As a general rule tooltips are only ever inserted for *short* forms of acronyms and never for the long form. Nesting is supported in the following way: tooltips of the “inner” acronyms are disabled and the one of the “outer” acronym is used.

The insertion can be checked visually by defining a macro

```
\providecommand\tooltip[2]{[PDF:#1][tooltip:#2]}
```

and use it via `\acsetup{tooltip-cmd = \tooltip}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\providecommand\tooltip[2]{[PDF:#1][tooltip:#2]}
\acsetup{
  tooltip-cmd = \tooltip ,
}

\DeclareAcronym{m}{
  short        = {m},
  long         = {milli},
  short-plural = {},
  long-plural  = {},
  class        = {SI-prefix},
  tooltip      = milli
}

\DeclareAcronym{g}{
  short        = {g},
  long         = {gramm},
  short-plural = {},
  long-plural  = {},
  class        = {SI-unit-derived},
  tooltip      = gramm
}

\DeclareAcronym{mg}{
  short        = {\acs{m}\acs{g}},
  long         = {\Acl{m}\acl{g}},
  short-plural = {},
  long-plural  = {},
  class        = {SI-unit-derived},
}

\begin{document}

\ac{g}\par
\ac{g}\par
\Ac{g}

\bigskip

\ac{m}\par
\acp{m}\par
\Acp{m}

\bigskip

\ac{mg}\par
\ac{mg}\par
\acf{mg}

\end{document}
```

---

**Original answer – for versions up to 1.6:**

The code below adds a `tooltip` property to acronyms that allows to specify the hover text for an acronym if it should differ from the long form. If not specified the long form is used. The code takes care that the tooltips are inserted for the short forms and the alternative forms but *not* on first use and *not* in the list of acronyms. This is done by redefining the corresponding internal commands.

The code uses the `pdfcomment` package and its `\pdftooltip` macro for generating the tooltips as an example. AlexG's `\tooltip` macro can just as easily be used, though, which means the integration into `acro` is independent from a tooltip generating package/code. Below the macro that needs to be adjusted is shown.

(I'm thinking of adding something like this to `acro`... but I'd like some feedback first. So far the feedback isn't overly enthusiastic...).

General usage

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage{acro}
\ExplSyntaxOn
...
\ExplSyntaxOff

% long form used as tooltip text:
\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = {CD},
  long  = {Compact Disc}
}
% custom tooltip text:
\DeclareAcronym{mc}{
  short   = {MC},
  long    = {Music Cassette},
  tooltip = {my mouse-over text}
}


\begin{document}

\ac{cd} \ac{mc}\par\vspace{1cm}
\ac{cd} \ac{mc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If another package/code for tooltips should be used then the definition in the code below

```
% #1: printed text
% #2: tool tip text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_tooltip:nn #1#2
  { \pdftooltip {#1} {#2} }
```

must be adjusted accordingly.

Here's the complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage{acro}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l__acro_tooltip_prop

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__acro_declare_tooltip:nn #1#2
  {
    \__acro_key_check:nn { #1 } { tooltip }
    \prop_put:Nnn \l__acro_tooltip_prop { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__acro_declare_tooltip:nn { V }

\keys_define:nn { acro / declare-acronym }
  {
    tooltip .code:n =
    \__acro_declare_tooltip:Vn \l__acro_current_key_tl { #1 } ,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_write_tooltip:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \prop_get:NnNTF \l__acro_tooltip_prop { #1 } \l__acro_tmpc_tl
      { \acro_tooltip:nn { #2 } { \l__acro_tmpc_tl } }
      { \acro_tooltip:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \acro_write_tooltip:nnn { nnV }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_use:n #1
  {
    % get the acronym and the plural settings:
    \acro_get:n { #1 }
    \acro_is_used:nTF { #1 }
      {
        % this is not the first time
        \__acro_indefinite:nn { #1 } { short }
        \__acro_acc_supp:nn
          { #1 }
          {
            \acro_write_tooltip:nnn
              { #1 }
              { \__acro_write_short:V \l__acro_short_tl }
              { \l__acro_long_tl }
          }
        \acro_after:n { #1 }
      }
      {
        % this is the first time
        \bool_gset_true:c { g__acro_#1_first_use_bool }
        \__acro_is_single:nTF { #1 }
          {
            \__acro_indefinite:nn { #1 } { long }
            \__acro_write_long:NV \l__acro_long_format_tl \l__acro_long_tl
          }
          { 
            \UseInstance { acro-first } { \l__acro_first_instance_tl }
              { #1 }
              { \l__acro_short_tl }
              { \l__acro_long_tl }
          }
      }
  }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_short:n #1
  {
    \acro_get:n { #1 }
    \acro_is_used:n { #1 }
    \__acro_indefinite:nn { #1 } { short }
    \__acro_is_single:nT { #1 }
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \acro_hyper_link:nn \use_ii:nn }
    \__acro_acc_supp:nn
      { #1 }
      {
        \acro_write_tooltip:nnn
          { #1 }
          { \__acro_write_short:V \l__acro_short_tl }
          { \l__acro_long_tl }
      }
    \acro_after:n { #1 }
  }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_alt:n #1
  {
    \acro_get:n { #1 }
    \acro_is_used:n { #1 }
    \__acro_indefinite:nn { #1 } { alt }
    \__acro_is_single:nT { #1 }
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \acro_hyper_link:nn \use_ii:nn }
    \__acro_acc_supp:nn
      { #1 }
      {
        \acro_write_tooltip:nnn
          { #1 }
          { \__acro_write_short:V \l__acro_alt_tl }
          { \l__acro_long_tl }
      }
    \acro_after:n { #1 }
  }

% use whatever command you like here:
% #1: printed text
% #2: tool tip text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_tooltip:nn #1#2
  { \pdftooltip {#1} {#2} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = {CD},
  long  = {Compact Disc}
}
\DeclareAcronym{mc}{
  short   = {MC},
  long    = {Music Cassette},
  tooltip = {my mouse-over text}
}


\begin{document}

\ac{cd} \ac{mc}\par\vspace{1cm}
\ac{cd} \ac{mc}

\aca{cd} \aca{mc}

\acs{cd} \acs{mc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @cgnieder I just realised you are the author of the acro package. I have been experimenting with your code which does not present the problem the `\tooltip` macro presents when integrated into the `\ac` redefinition (see my initial question's edit). It runs pretty smoothly though as feedback the first two things that I can offer for improvement are 1) the tooltip click box is smaller than the word itself, I think if it were slightly bigger it would be a feature that people would stumble across in a PDF more easily 2) the macro does not treat alternative `\aca` commands. I will offer more

Comment: I will keep you posted of any other feedback I can give while using the macro. Thank you for sharing it! I think it would be a lovely addition to the acro package.

Comment: @Fiztban I can't help with the tooltips themselves: they are created by the `pdfcomment` in my code. But the package provides lot's of options so it should be possible to customize the output. You could even use any other package to create the tooltips (or use AlexG's code) by changing the definition `\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_tooltip:nn #1#2 { \pdftooltip {#1} {#2} }`. (My code above mainly provides an integration of a tooltip functionality into `acro`.) As for `\aca`: I'm aware of that. Also `\acs` and some others. The above is a draft of changes that could be integrated into `acro`

Comment: Thank you for explaining your code, I am learning a lot since last week when I started so I appreciate the time you have taken. My feedback was simply what I could offer with my beginners view of LaTeX, I will experiment with other tooltips though your code suits me perfectly for the time being. Thank you

Comment: @Fiztban I added support for `\aca` and `\acs` and friends

Comment: you are a technical wizard, thank you for you help. I spent a couple hours last night trying to make sense of the macro language, didn't get very far though it seems to have similarities with the linux language.

Comment: @Fiztban Well, I know the code since I wrote the package :) It is written in expl3 (the programming layer of LaTeX3). If you search this site you'll find many examples, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84605

Comment: @cgneider indeed you did write it yourself :D. Thank you for explaining it I will look into it when I get some time to experiment with making my own macros. For now I will remain content with my limited knowledge that packages do things with their macro's that I have no need yet to tamper with.

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of `acro`, the following code (originally by Denis Bitouzé) works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = {CD},
  long  = {Compact Disc}
 }
\DeclareAcronym{mc}{
  short   = {MC},
  long    = {Music Cassette},
  pdfcomment = {my mouse-over text}
}
 
\acsetup{
  pdfcomments/use=true
}

\begin{document}

 \ac{cd} \ac{mc}\par\vspace{1cm}
 \ac{cd} \ac{mc}

 \aca{cd} \aca{mc}

 \acs{cd} \acs{mc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Bitbucket issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/50/support-for-mouse-over), for versions 2.0b or greater the code of [clemens' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161521/) reduces to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\usepackage{acro}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\acro_declare_simple_key:n {tooltip}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_write_tooltip:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \prop_get:NnNTF \l__acro_tooltip_prop {#1} \l__acro_tmpa_tl
      { \acro_tooltip:nV {#2} \l__acro_tmpa_tl }
      { \acro_tooltip:nn {#2} {#3} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \acro_write_tooltip:nnn { nnV }

% use whatever command you like for creating tooltips here:
% #1: printed text
% #2: tool tip text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \acro_tooltip:nn #1#2
  { \pdftooltip {#1} {#2} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \acro_tooltip:nn { nV }

\cs_set_protected:Npn \acro_write_compact:nn #1#2
  {
    \acro_get_ending_form:nn {#1} {#2}
    \acro_acc_supp:nn
      {#1}
      {
        \acro_write_tooltip:nnn
          {#1}
          {
            \use:c {acro_write_#2:nv} {#1} {l__acro_#2_tl}
            \acro_endings:nn {#1} {#2}
          }
          { \l__acro_long_tl }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = {CD},
  long  = {Compact Disc}
}
\DeclareAcronym{mc}{
  short   = {MC},
  long    = {Music Cassette},
  tooltip = {my mouse-over text}
}


\begin{document}

\ac{cd} \ac{mc}\par\vspace{1cm}
\ac{cd} \ac{mc}

\aca{cd} \aca{mc}

\acs{cd} \acs{mc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are who I think you are you seem to have two disctinct accounts, http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/85774 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82471. The stackexchange staff can merge them for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I dont know why but the code you just gave does not post mouse overs

Comment: @Fiztban I got it confirmed that mouse over tooltips *are* produced with above definition. It does *not* work for the *first* appearance of the acronyms due to a missing usage of `\acro_write_compact:nn` in `acro`. This will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I now know why it wasn't working, the package was not updating even though MikTeX said it had been, a re-install and then a later manual update worked.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 2.1, code can be reduced to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tooltip]{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{cd}{
  short = {CD},
  long  = {Compact Disc}
}
\DeclareAcronym{mc}{
  short   = {MC},
  long    = {Music Cassette},
  tooltip = {my mouse-over text}
}


\begin{document}

 \ac{cd} \ac{mc}\par\vspace{1cm}
 \ac{cd} \ac{mc}

 \aca{cd} \aca{mc}

 \acs{cd} \acs{mc}

\end{document}
```

I got mouse-overs in all eight cases.

See [256627](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256627/) for the case of nested acronyms.

Comment: IMHO you should update [your other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263997/) instead of posting a new one – especially since the other answer is obsolete now. Do you really have three accounts?

Comment: So `pdfcomment` is no longer needed for this to work?

Comment: @Fiztban yes, it still is required. Have a look at my updated answer where I explain what v2.1 does

Comment: The above acronym popups work beautifully in pdf viewing with acroread in my Ubuntu 18.04.  But they do not pop up in evince, ocular,  xpdf , chrome pdf reader, and worse, also not in MacOS Preview.  80% of my intended readers use Macs so adding popups to acronyms is useless.  Is there another way producing popups in all pdf viewers?

Comment: With acro 3.8 (mikTeX) I get an error message that the property `tooltip' does not exist. There are no pop-ups visible in the output with Acrobat Reader nor SumatraPDF.