# mouse over (highlight) acronyms using acronym package. is that possible?

Tags: macros, acronyms, pdftricks

Is it possible to highlight acronyms (mouse over shows the acronym definition) by using the [acronym](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package \ac ....?

In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161464/are-mouse-over-definitions-of-acronyms-possible), there is a macro that was working somehow **but** by using the [acro](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) package. I tried to change the macro to make it adaptable to the [acronym](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package (which is too late to be replaced and must be used), but unfortunately without great results.

I'm using MikTex 2.9.

Comment: Javascript can be used with LaTeX.

Comment: As you noted, the `acro` package can do this, and even more directly via `\usepackage[tooltip]{acro}`.  See, for example, my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304131/how-to-avoid-hyperlinks-with-usepackagetooltipacro/304133#304133