# How to avoid hyperlinks with \usepackage[tooltip]{acro}?

Tags: pdfcomment, acro

I have finally managed to assign tooltips to all acronyms in my document thanks to `\usepackage[tooltip]{acro}`. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tooltip]{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{ABC}{short = ABC, long = alphabet}

\begin{document}
\section{ABC} \label{sec:ABC}
\ac{ABC}

\section{Comments}
Here are comments on section~\ref{sec:ABC}.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this package option also assignes hyperlinks to all internal references (like the `\ref{sec:ABC}` in the example above), printing a colored rectangle around them. While I do like the hyperlinks, the colored rectangle looks horrible.

How can I remove the rectangles again without losing the tooltip function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I invoked `hyperref` separately from `acro`, and using the `[hidelinks]` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[tooltip]{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{ABC}{short = ABC, long = alphabet}

\begin{document}
\section{ABC} \label{sec:ABC}
\ac{ABC}

\section{Comments}
Here are comments on section~\ref{sec:ABC}.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comparison without the `[hidelinks]`:

[image]

Comment: Although this works the general advice is to load `hyperref` as late as possible so it can react to other packages.

Comment: Thinking about it this may lead to an option clash. But there's always `\hypersetup` (IIRC)…

Comment: @Clemens I am not a regular `hyperref` user.  However, I did confirm that the method also works if `hyperref` is loaded lastly.