# Embedding equation's source code to PDF?

Tags: pdf, embedding

Suppose  that I have a MME:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is test
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

we know that we can copy the text content `This is test` directly, while on the other hand, "copy the equation" turns out has bad format. I am wondering is there any package (e.g. [navigator](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/generic/navigator/navigator-doc.pdf)) or method that can copy the source code of the equation instead the equation itself?

Comment: Good idea, good question. Maybe you can use this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161464/4736 or the packages cooltooltips, pdfcomment or fancytooltips (written from memory, didn't check).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use