# How can I get pop-ups with the explanation when I have the mouse pointer on an acronym or citation

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, acronyms

More and more texts are nowadays published electronically. In such electronic publications, an explanation may pop up when the mouse hovers on a text, like the page-previews on Wikipedia or the name of the program on an icon in many operating systems.

In just the same way, I would like the expansion of an acronym to pop up when users hover their mouse over it. This way, they could learn the meaning without having to go to the list of acronyms, which after all interrupts the reading flow. Is there a way to achieve that in LaTeX? I am currently using the `acronym` and `hyperref` packages, but could still switch to something else if required.

Similarly, it would be nice if the full reference would pop up if one hovers over a citation (created, for example, with `biblatex`).

Thanks for any advice

Engelbert

Comment: eforms  package trigger events (page 21)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are mouse over definitions of acronyms possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161464/are-mouse-over-definitions-of-acronyms-possible)

Comment: For citations, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356/35864.